# Docker- Containers-saloer (Multiple copies of a deployed app in multiple containers, saleor)

Tags: django, docker, containers, saleor

i have deployed saleor by cloning it from
< https://github.com/AirnFire/saleor-platform >.
i want to create multiple images of this app and deploy them on different containers, can anybody guide me how to do that.

Comment: I think we need more information here. There are multiple ways of doing what you're asking for, depending on what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide more details about what you're trying to accomplish? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use docker swarm for that.
Take a look at
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/swarm-deploy/